# Best Practice for Making Sample/Preview Changes to JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a web app backed by spring boot/jpa within which users can upload a file via the UI to make changes to JPA entities.  I would like to return those changes as a 'preview' to the UI, without actually updating the database.  I'm wondering what's considered the best practice for manipulating these JPA entities without actually making updates to the database until the user has approved the changes ... gather these records via CRUD to update?  Pull the entity and then detach to manipulate and return?  Return an updated clone?

Answer (score 0):

Create a DTO(Data transfer object) with the fields that you need to preview, and when the user approve the changes, then use that DTO to update the database.